# tailwind css config file background image issue

Tags: css, filepath, tailwind-css

I am not getting background image output from the `tailwind.Config.Js`. Tailwind.Config.Js perfectly generate the background image but when I see the output on browser it's showing image `404` .

here is my code sample of
tailwind.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  purge: [],
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    extend: {
      // backgroundImage: theme => ({
      //   'body-bg': "url('./../images/px1.gif')",
      // })
      backgroundImage: theme => ({
        'hero-pattern': "url('../images/px1.gif')",
       })
    },
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

here is the webpack setup

```
let mix = require("laravel-mix");

mix.js("src/js/app.js", "js/app.js")
mix.css("src/css/app.css", "css/app.css")
  .options({
    postCss: [require("tailwindcss")],
  }).setPublicPath('public')
```

here is the folder structure

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NAEa.png)

i am getting this output css

```
.bg-hero-pattern {
  background-image: url(/images/px1.gif?9ee64f464ce65b98bb9e4168105dc9b3);
}
```

output CSS should be this

```
.bg-hero-pattern {
  background-image: url(../images/px1.gif?9ee64f464ce65b98bb9e4168105dc9b3);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I  hope this answer will help for those who faced same problem like me.

After few research on my code I found the solution and it work for me.  I need to add this       `processcssurls: true,` in the  `mix.Option`  . You can learn it for here  [Laravel Mix Options](https://laravel-mix.com/docs/5.0/options)

Answer (score 4):

add `~` before path file

```
theme: {
   extend: {
   backgroundImage: theme => ({
    'hero-pattern': "url('~/images/px1.gif')",
   })
   },
},
```